# Is it possible to add or change intents/entities/dialog externally through restful API for watson conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson, watson-conversation

Im wondering ,if there is a way where we can add Intents/Entities/Dialogues through the Restful service as this will allow my application to be extremely dynamic adding its own entities/intents through interactions with the user.Can someone let me know is this possible or not?

Kind regards harish

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible using the Workspace API. Example:

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#intents

From what you described, be aware that modifying intents+entities will trigger a retraining event. Changing a dialog tree live can possibly cause users interactions to reset.

Also the workspace API is currently free to use, but is rate limited. So good for updating a workspace, but not in a live interaction environment.